# How do I upgrade netbeans with packageOverride in configruation.nix?

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to change the version of netbeans using [this](https://nixos.org/wiki/Nix_Modifying_Packages) guide. I'm using the config.nix expression inside my `/etc/configuration.nix` This is what it looks like:

```
 nixpkgs.config = {
    packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
      myNetbeans = pkgs.stdenv.lib.overrideDerivation pkgs.netbeans ( oldAttrs: {
        name = "netbeans-8.1";
        src = fetchurl {
          url = ttp://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/final/zip/netbeans-8.1-201510222201.zip;
          md5 = "361ce18421761a057bad5cb6cf7b58f4";
        };
      });
    };
  };
```

I believe I have everything right but it is unable to find fetchurl and I get these errors.

> error: undefined variable ‘fetchurl’ at
>   /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:83:15 (use ‘--show-trace’ to show
>   detailed location information) error: undefined variable ‘fetchurl’ at
>   /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:83:15 (use ‘--show-trace’ to show
>   detailed location information) building the system configuration...
>   error: undefined variable ‘fetchurl’ at
>   /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:83:15 (use ‘--show-trace’ to show
>   detailed location information)

How can I fix this error and get netbeans upgraded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there. The fetchurl variable is only present/defined in the scope of the pkgs set. That's the cause of the error message saying the fetchurl variable is undefined. So simply access the fetchurl attribute from the scope of the pkgs set, i.e. `pkgs.fetchurl`, the same as you have for `pkgs.netbeans`.

If you need to access lots of attributes from a set then make use of the **with** nix language construct ([ref](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-constructs)).

PS you'll need to correct the typo in `url = http://`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked great! I also had to add myNetbeans to the packages. I guess I could just use netbeans...

Comment: Do you mean because you then had to install it into your .nix-profile using the imperative `nix-env -i`? If so you could instead install it declaratively by setting `environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.myNetbeans ];` ([ref](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-customising-packages)). The flexibility to customise packages as you desire is a really strong feature of nix.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. I put this all into my configuration.nix.